# How can I edit matching files if the paths contain whitespace in bash?

Tags: bash, quoting

I sometimes `grep` (or `rg` aka `ripgrep` or `ag` aka `silversearcher`) for things and then want to edit the matching files. For the editor part I use bash's history.

```bash
~$ rg someThing
./path/to/some/file.txt
1:someThing in there.
~$ vim $(!! -l)
```

This works fine unless the path contains spaces, and then the shell splits on whitespace and vim gets passed the wrong file names.

How can I get these quoted?

Comment: Since this is something you sometimes do, i.e. not a one-off, then consider creating a function to do it like `rv() { rg "$@" && vim "$(!! -l)"; }` so in future you can just do `rv someThing` instead of having to remember that syntax. There are probably better ways to do what you want, though, ask a new question if you'd like help with that.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton! Good idea. I don't always use both commands together; only when I get a reasonable number of hits. (If not, I need different search terms.) I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vim "$(!! -l)"` works for me ...

Comment: Thanks, I must have messed up my quoting when I tried earlier.